# Navigating object as string to extract information using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, object, indexof

So I need to extract certain data from a object which I don't control that is returned to me and is always of varying length.

The formatted response as a string I get is like:

```
{
    "questionId": 18196101,
    "externalQuestionId": "bcc38f7d30ea44ad908d8166dafa5556",
    "category": "Employment Law",
    "secondaryCategory": "",
    "partnerName": "",
    "questionTitle": "I sold my business but was offered a job with the company as",
    "questionText": "I sold my business but was offered a job with the company as manager..."
}
```

So basically the string is:     `'{"questionId":18196101,"externalQuestionId":"bcc38f7d30ea44ad908d8166dafa5556","category":"Employment Law","secondaryCategory":"","partnerName":"","questionTitle":"I sold my business but was offered a job with the company as","questionText":"I sold my business but was offered a job with the company as manager..."}'`

Now what I have is the whole text of those questions to say, so both the `questionTitle` and `questionText` is known to me. I can then search for their indexes inside that string, I do that because this object is a very small part of and can be in any place of a much bigger response.

What I need to extract from this is the `externalQuestionId`, or in this example `"bcc38f7d30ea44ad908d8166dafa5556"`.

All of those numbers are always different so I must rely on getting the indexes of the known parameters.

So basically, I have that string, I can get the starting index of `questionTitle` and I need to get the `externalQuestionId` data.

How can I for example, get the index of the nearest `externalQuestionId` when I have the index of the `questionTitle`?

Comment: if you feel you *must* do it as a string operation, then `.lastIndexOf()` with the known index of `questionTitle` as the second argument. (But I'd be more inclined to convert that JSON to an actual object and use object/array operations to find the right property.)

Comment: So is your string a valid JSON representation of a JavaScript object? If so you can use JSON.parse(string) to get a normal JS object.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes I am aware that it's much better to use the object/array operations to navigate the object and also about the JSON.parse function but the response I get is thousands of lines of values long with multiple copies, duplicates many many layers into the object from which some are random and varying so navigating it as an object is not possible.

Comment: Parsing and looping through a few thousand JSON objects usually is no big deal for browsers nowdays. Besides, you dont really have another option, because you somehow have to extract the text from the response...

Comment: Navigating a complicated nested object to search for one property with a specific value isn't that difficult, a fairly generic recursive property traversal function can handle that. But if you don't want that I already mentioned a way to do it as a string operation.

Comment: @nnnnnn Using `.lastIndexOf` and then navigating through the rest helped thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) for suggesting the use of `.lastIndexOf()`.

I created a simple function for my specific case that takes that full text and a fragment that I have and returns my required data.

```js
function getQuestionId(fullText, textFragment) {
 var newString = fullText.substr(fullText.lastIndexOf("externalQuestionId", fullText.indexOf(textFragment)));
 return newString.substr(21, newString.indexOf(",") - 22);
}

var str = '{"questionId":18196101,"externalQuestionId":"bcc38f7d30ea44ad908d8166dafa5556","category":"Employment Law","secondaryCategory":"","partnerName":"","questionTitle":"I sold my business but was offered a job with the company as","questionText":"I sold my business but was offered a job with the company as manager..."}'
var frag = 'I sold my business but was offered a job with the company as","questionText":"I sold my business b';

console.log(getQuestionId(str, frag));
```